# A numpy.arange style function with array inputs

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy arrays of start indices and end indices from which I'd like to construct a flattened array of ranges.

e.g. with inputs

```
s = np.array([1,2,3])
e = np.array([4,5,10])
```

and output

```
array([1,2,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

any way to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

How about just

```
np.concatenate([np.arange(x, y) for x, y in zip(s, e)])
```

Comment: @Chris - While @tkerwin's answer is perfectly suited to your case, you might also want to have a look at `np.r_`. It's a convenient way to manually build up a sequence like this. `np.r_[1:4, 2:5, 3:10]` will create the same sequence. It's probably not what you want to use in this case, but is very convenient in some cases, and it's good to know about.